# Facebook like button loaded by jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I am trying to load a #content div of news_092612.html into another page using jquery.  Everything from #content is loading fine except for the facebook like button.  Here is the script I am using, I believe I am supposed to incorporate a parse function somewhere to get the buttons to reload in the new #newswrapper.  I've searched and tried, but I'm hitting a wall.  Thanks in advance!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#newswrapper1').load('news_092612.html #content');

 });
```

Also here is the original page that I'm getting #content from.
http://www.spadeballink.com/GALLOWS/news_092612.html

As well as the other page that I'm trying to load #content to.
http://www.spadeballink.com/GALLOWS/TheGoddamnGallows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Facebook widget is loaded by the Facebook SDK, which is included in the specific news file, but not the page you're trying to load your #content div into.

Try adding this code into the page gallows.html page:

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thank you so much, I should have just asked a week ago and saved the headache! Haha

Comment: You may also want to look at bringing in the FB metadata from the posts as well, they're the `og` pieces. They help with the sharing process, and so much more.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely do that.  I'm hoping you can help with another problem that has arose.  The container (#newswrapper1) div is not resizing when the facebook buttons are clicked. I have searched and tried everything I thought would work to no avail.  Thanks for anymore input!