# Facebook "like" button doesn't display on some content

Tags: jquery, facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm very new to Javascript and JQuery but was able to find something online called "organic tabs" (http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/) and incorporate into the page I am working on, which is essentially a product gallery. You can see what I've done here:

http://www.fat-hair.com/wildfire_products.html

The trouble is, my client wants a facebook "like" button to appear on every product along with a pinterest "pin it" button. For some reason the JQuery is conflicting with the facebook like button, except on the default product. I've made a version of the page without the JQuery and have confirmed that without it, the FB buttons appear as they should. **NOTE: This problem only occurs in Firefox and IE**. In Chrome and Safari it seems fine.

http://www.fat-hair.com/wildfire_products-trblsht.html

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on and how to correct it? For the record, I tried to follow the advice of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946345/facebook-like-button-loaded-by-jquery-not-working) but it did not work for me.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by choosing the IFRAME code from facebook instead of the HTML5 coode, <a href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/">Here.</a>

Not sure why the other way didn't work, so if anyone has any thoughts on that, that would be awesome. But it is fixed.

Comment: You should add a formal answer rather than have your answer in a comment, then shortly after that you will be able to mark it as the accepted answer.